# Django admin. Limit choices of many to many field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Many to Many field. I'd like to limit the choices the admin shows in its M2M widget.

I have a model like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    b_field = models.ManyToManyField(B)

class B(models.Model):
    available = models.BooleanField()
```

How do I limit the B objects shown in the widget only to those who have `available = True`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) option might help you,

> Sets a limit to the available choices for this field when this field is rendered using a ModelForm or the admin (by default, all objects in the queryset are available to choose). Either a dictionary, a Q object, or a callable returning a dictionary or Q object can be used.

For eg,

```
class A(models.Model):
    b_field = models.ManyToManyField(B, limit_choices_to={'available': True})
```